# Laravel rollback saved changes if error is encountered while saving child model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

For example, I have a User hasMany Books relationship.

Let's take this scenario.

I **successfully** saved the User (which is the parent model), but there was an error while saving one of the Books (which is the child model). Is it possible to delete the saved parent *(only if there are errors encountered while saving the parent and/or child)* then redirect to another page?

Actually I don't have any code to provide. I'm currently planning on how to build the code, and I have thought of this idea.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can delete it manually. But there's a better way - use transactions instead (if your db supports). The advantages of using a transaction are many but for your scenario these 2 are most relevant

1. If anything goes wrong you can just call `DB::rollBack()` and it will be like the queries were never run.
2. Manually deleting will still progress the primary key/auto increment/sequence id. So if User (id =4) gets saved but unfortunately while saving that user's book you encounter an error and now you delete the user. So the next time you save another user it will have id = 5 and not 4; this will give gaps in the auto-increment id which not a problem technically speaking but doesn't look good. This problem is totally avoided in case of transactions

Here is the basic structure of a transaction based operation in laravel

```
DB::beginTransaction(); // <-- first line  

try{
    // code ....
    // saved User
    // code ...
    // saved Book
    if($saved)
    $childModelSaved = true; 
    else
    $childModelSaved = false; 
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
     $childModelSaved = false;
}

if($childModelSaved)
{
    DB::commit(); // YES --> finalize it 
}
else
{
    DB::rollBack(); // NO --> some error has occurred undo the whole thing
}
```

Comment: WIll try this one. Thank you!